# Angularjs Uib bootstrap, auto closing modal window

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I'm using 'angular-bootstrap' (v. 2.5.0) modal windows. I faced a problem, when I having opened window, going to the other browser tab, to look for some information, and when I'm returned to that page ( in 5 - 10 min ), the modal window is automatically closed, but modal window should be opened. Maybe someone had  faced the same problem and know how to prevent this

Comment: can you show your code with `$uibModal.open(...)`?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, I had code that tracks activity and automatically closes modal window if there is no action in 10 minutes